# UUID instead of UDID while adding device

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile

I am trying to add a device in `Devices` column at [apple developer](http://developer.apple.com) site, to create a provisioning profile to test my push notification.

But when I tried to add the device id I found that now it is asking for UUID instead of UDID & when I am entering UDID in UUID field it is giving error `invalid values` & it is taking only **36 Characters** as input.

Screenshot attached:
[image: Add Device]

I am not able to understand what's going wrong. If anyone has idea, please help.

Comment: Maybe you have a pending contract

Comment: It says "Name you device and enter its Unique Device Identifier(UUID)". Unique Device Identifier means UDID. Try adding the UDID again.

Comment: @Andrea: No, there is no pending contract. All terms & conditions are accepted.

Comment: @OmerWaqasKhan: Tried many times & also noted that UDID contains 40 characters but UUID contains 36 characters & this text field is also taking 36 characters as input.

Comment: I have just opened my account and checked. It says "Name your device and enter its Unique Device Identifier (UDID)." There must be something with your account. Apple is still asking for the UDID

Answer (score 0):

If you observe properly you have opened Mac Apps section, which asks for UUID, Open iOS App section to add your iOS Device. In case you are looking to add a MAC device indeed, ask so, i will tell you where to find UUID...

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the Mac Apps as iOS Apps instead of Mac Apps. Then you can add UDID.
Hope it helps.